# js - width and height of usable space on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to get the width and height of the usable space on a page? - with other words: the maximum size of a rectangle that can be put on the page without having scrollbars.

I am using a jquery datatable where the whole content is scrollable - I would like to set the "sScrollY" value to the maximum possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a wrapper on the other content and use the following JavaScript to get the amount of available space on the page.

```
var wHeight = parseFloat(document.getElementById("wrapper").style.height);
var pHeight = $("body").height();
var empty = pHeight - wHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

if I well understood, try this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/exojes/3/edit

Js

```
$(function() {

    var div = $('div').eq(0),
        de  = document.documentElement;

    div.css({
      width: de['offsetWidth'] + 'px',
      height: de['offsetHeight'] + 'px' 
    });

});
```

Css

```
div {
   /* box-sizing is useful if you're using borders or inner paddings */
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
   box-sizing: border-box; 

   border: 2px green dotted;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; left: 0;
}
```

---

Otherwise, without invoving javascript you could just use this CSS only

```
html, body, div {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}

div {
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
   box-sizing: border-box; 
   border: 2px green dotted;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you the width and height of the window

```
width = $(window).width();
height = $(window).height();
```

Comment: thanks, but I would like to know the space that is free (if there e.g. an img in the page, I would like to know the space under it)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `width` and `height` of `body` and use it

```
var height = $("body").height();
var width = $("body").width();
```